# Restricting JS links from search engine's crawling

Tags: php, javascript, web-crawler

I would like to prevent google from following links I have in JS.
I didn't find how to do that in robots.txt
Am I looking in the wrong place?

Some more information:
I'm seeing google is crawling those pages although the links only appear in JS. 
The reason I don't want him to crawl is that this content depends on external API's which I don't want to waste my rate limit with them on google crawlers and only per user demand

Answer (score 0):

Direct from google ->

http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=96569

Comment: I've read in wikipedia: "The nofollow attribute value is not meant for blocking access to content, or for preventing content to be indexed by search engines. The proper methods for blocking search engine spiders from accessing content on a website or for preventing them from including the content of a page in their index are the Robots Exclusion Standard (robots.txt)". That's why I thought this was not the right solution for me. Your thoughts?

Comment: Also I understood it should mainly dis affect the ranking of the page I'm linking to, but not to avoid crawling of it

Answer (score 0):

Google probably won't find any links you have hidden in JS, but someone else could link to the same place.

It isn't links that matter though, it is URLs. Just specify the URLs you don't want search engines to visit in the robots.txt. The fact that you usually expose them to the browser via JS is irrelevant.

If you really want to limit access to the content, then just reducing discoverability probably isn't sufficient and you should put an authentication layer (e.g. password protection) in place.

Comment: I'm seeing google is crawling those pages. Also, it's not the content I'm worried about. This content depends on external API's which I don't want to waste my rate limit with them on google crawlers and only per user demand

Comment: Can I specify in robots.txt not to follow JS urls?

Comment: You aren't trying to protect a "JS URL". That's just a piece of code that returns a document. You're trying to protect an HTTP URL (presumably one that is used via the JS). Protect that.

Comment: But I can't really generate a list of those url's and also it's quite a big list that can constantly grow. So I thought that maybe protecting all HTTP URL that the JS document holds might help out...

Comment: robots.txt operates on a directory basis, structure your URLs so they all hang off the same directory, then block that.